# how to filter a query base on a field of object after $lookup in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to get comments of a post-blog sorted by top-like(rate)
Comment Model:

```
const CommentSchema = new Schema({
    content: {type: String, maxLength: 100, required: true},
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    blog: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Blog', required: true},
    reactions: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Reaction'}],
},{ timestamps: true})

const ReactionSchema = new Schema({
    user: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
    comment: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment', required: true},
    date: {type: Schema.Types.Date, default: Date.now, required: true}
})
```

my query:

```
this.model.Reaction.aggregate([            
        {
          $group: {
            _id: "$comment",
            num: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        },
        { $sort: { num: -1 } },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "comments",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "Com",
          }
        },
        { $unwind: "$Com" },
        {
            $match: {"Com.blog": '629af177e03ab4cfe845a9a4'}
        },
        {
          $project: {
            content: "$Com.content",
            num: 1,
          }
        },
      ])
```

but $match after $lookup isn't accept! I try to use "$filter" also, but it get a "array " and a have a Object!
my query work without $match. but a need to filter comments base on blog-id

Comment: From your `CommentSchema`, the `blog` is `ObjectId` type. While, in your query you are providing the value in `string`. So the filter isn't working as both values `Com.blog` and the provided value never be true. Try to convert the value to `ObjectId` with [`$toObjectId`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toObjectId/) before comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this,

```
this.model.Reaction.aggregate([            
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$comment",
        num: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    },
    { $sort: { num: -1 } },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "comments",
        localField: "_id",
        foreignField: "_id",
        as: "Com",
      }
    },
    { $unwind: "$Com" },
    {
        $match: {"Com.blog": mongoose.Types.ObjectId('629af177e03ab4cfe845a9a4')}
    },
    {
      $project: {
        content: "$Com.content",
        num: 1,
      }
    },
  ])
```